# exams num_to_schoice to include wrong alternatives

Tags: r, r-exams

I am using `num_to_choice` to generate 5 options for a numeric exercise using the `r exams` package.

I want my `sc$questions` to include the correct solution (`res`) plus two calculated wrong solutions (`err1` and `err2`). I am using this code:

```
sc <- num_to_schoice(res, digits=3, wrong=c(err1, err2))
```

I do get the five options generated, one with the correct solution (`res`), but none of the other four options include `err1` and `err2`. Reading the `num_to_choice` documentation I find:

> "The wrong solutions can be provided or are generated randomly. If
> wrong is provided only up to 2 elements of it are used in order to
> assure some random solutions."

However, in my case none of the `err1` or `err2`  options are included in the `sc$questions`. What am I missing here? How can I force the `err` options to be included in the `sc$questions`?

Here is an reproducible example:

```
v <- c(1225,4000,1372,974,956,940,1532,969,1070,685,220,407,903,239,283,368,483,352,77,699)
res <- sd(v)
err1 <- IQR(v)
err2 <- sqrt(var(v)*(length(v-1)/length(v)))
set.seed(1)
sc <- num_to_schoice(res, digits=3, wrong=c(err1, err2), range=c(0,max(v)))
```

and here is the solution generated by `sc$questions`:

The result is "specified 'wrong' is too small for 'delta'"

Comment: I tried to guess what the source of the problems might be, see my answer below. If this doesn't solve your problem, please include a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In your example

In your case `err2` and `res` are identical:

```
identical(res, err2)
## [1] TRUE
```

That is why `num_to_schoice()` returns `NULL` along with a warning that should inform you that the difference from `res` to the `wrong` argument is too small for the given `delta`. Hence, it is not possible to include `res` as the correct solution and `err2` as a wrong solution.

The source of the problem is that you compute

```
length(v - 1)
```

which is the same as `length(v)` rather than the intended

```
length(v) - 1
```

If you do

```
err2 <- sqrt(var(v) * (length(v) - 1)/length(v))
```

Then you get the desired

```
set.seed(1)
num_to_schoice(res, digits = 3, wrong = c(err1, err2))
## $solutions
## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
## 
## $questions
## [1] "$819.235$"  "$634.000$"  "$996.905$"  "$840.517$"  "$1222.200$"
```

#### More generally

By design `num_to_schoice()` is rather conservative: If it thinks it cannot find a set of items with the desired properties it returns `NULL` rather than trying to find an approximate solution. This is to avoid randomly getting exercises that might be simpler than intended.

Another typical example is that the `range` is too small and/or the `delta` too large to produce a list of five answer options that conform with all arguments. For example, let's assume we have the following correct solution and two distractors:

```
res <- 1.234
err1 <- 2.345
err2 <- 3.456
```

Then, the command you posted above will not work:

```
num_to_schoice(res, digits = 3, wrong = c(err1, err2))
## NULL
## Warning message:
## In num_to_schoice(res, digits = 3, wrong = c(err1, err2)) :
##   specified 'range' is too small for 'delta'
```

The reason is that the default `delta` is 1 and the default `range` is `c(0.5, 1.5) * res` in this case. And this is not large enough to accomodate five answers with a minimum `delta` of 1.

But if you increase the `range` (or alternatively decrease the `delta`) you get:

```
set.seed(1)
num_to_schoice(res, digits = 3, wrong = c(err1, err2), range = c(0, 10))
## $solutions
## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
## 
## $questions
## [1] "$3.456$" "$2.345$" "$4.496$" "$1.234$" "$9.195$"
```

where `res` ends up in position 4 while `err1` and `err2` are in positions 2 and 1, respectively.

Comment: Thanks @Achim Zeiles for the fast answer. I  added an reproducible example to the question above.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I updated my answer correspondingly. The error is that `length(v-1)` is the same as `length(v)` which is not what you intended...

Comment: Thanks!,... corrected. I still have cases where the range is too small for delta (since r is random generated), even if use range=c(0, max(v)). i see now that the problem is due to the similar values of res and err1...

Comment: Either choose a smaller delta or drop the wrong solutions that do not have a sufficient distance from the correct solution. (Also please don't forget to accept the answer. )

Comment: yes, you are right. The correct solution uses the sample standard-deviation estimator, one of the incorrect solutions uses the population sd estimator... small differences for large samples. Setting the delta=0.01 solved the problem. Thanks for the great num_to_schoice function!.